# Groovy literal regex /\\/ is not compiling

Tags: java, regex, groovy, backslash

I have a path in Windows:

```
assert f.toString() == 'C:\\path\\to\\some\\dir'
```

I need to convert the backslashes `\` to forward slashes `/`. Using Java syntax, I would write:

```
assert f.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/') == 'C:/path/to/some/dir'
```

But I am studying Groovy, so I thought I would write a literal regular expression:

```
assert f.toString().replaceAll(/\\/, '/') == 'C:/path/to/some/dir'
```

This throws a compilation error:

> unexpected token: ) ==  at line: 4, column: 42

I started looking on the internet, and found several comments suggesting that this particular regex literal would not work, instead you would have to use a workaround like `/\\+/`. But this obviously changes the semantics of the regex.

I cannot really understand why `/\\/` does not work. Maybe somebody does?

Comment: Inside slashy strings, a backslash is still a special escaping symbol.

Comment: If the `+?` operator works in Groovy, `/\\+?/` would not change the semantics.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, that explains why using a dollar slashy string _does_ work: `$/\\/$`. But there is no way around this?

Comment: Well, you may use a  character class - `/[\\]/`. You see, you cannot have `\/` at the end, it ruins the slashy string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, but then I would use as much characters as I would with a Java string (so no point using a regex literal in this case), and I would be introducing a pointless character class, that could possibly confuse other developers.

Comment: So, basically, your question is: how to put a ``\`` at the end of the slashy string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, maybe that would be a logical generalization of this question.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Use a limiting quantifier after it - `/\\{1}/`. Is that clear enough for "other developers"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I thought of that myself, but it conveys the idea that the quantifier is somehow important, and _not_ just some workaround to make the regex literal work. But thanks for your input.

Comment: @horcrux Your solution would work equally well.

Comment: The quantifier is not important. You might as well use `.replaceAll(/\\(?:)/, '/')`. The main point is that you need to separate the ``\`` from the `/` trailing slashy string delimiter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What I meant was that, using the workarounds, one would basically put no-ops in a regular expression, and to keep the code maintainable (the original goal of using a regex literal), one would not want to put in potentially confusing stuff. So, it's probably best to just use a Java string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` at the end of the slashy string ruins it.

The main point is that you need to separate the `\` from the `/` trailing slashy string delimiter.

It can be done in several ways:

```
println(f.replaceAll('\\\\', '/'))   // Using a single-quoted string literal with 4 backslashes, Java style
println(f.replaceAll(/[\\]/, '/'))   // Wrapping the backslash with character class
println(f.replaceAll(/\\{1}/, '/'))  // Using a {1} limiting quantifier
println(f.replaceAll(/\\(?:)/, '/')) // Using an empty group after it
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/tX50hv).

However, you may use *dollar slashy strings* to use the backslash at the end of the string:

```
f.replaceAll($/\\/$, '/')
```

See the [demo](https://ideone.com/kqHPHC) and check [this thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2701):

> *Slashy strings*: backslash escapes end of line chars and slash, `$` escapes interpolated variables/closures, **can't have backslash as last character**, empty string not allowed. Examples: `def a_backslash_b = /a\b/; def a_slash_b = /a\/b/;`
>
> *Dollar slashy strings*: backslash escapes only EOL, `$` escapes interpolated variables/closures and itself if required and slash if required, use `$$` to have `$` as last character or to have a `$` before an identifier or curly brace or slash, use `$/` to have a slash before a `$`, empty string not allowed. Examples: `def a_backslash_b = $/a\b/$; def a_slash_b = $/a/b/$; def a_dollar_b = $/a$$b/$;`

Comment: Do you have a link, by any chance, explaining what is and what isn't allowed in a slashy string? The [official documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_slashy_string) doesn't mention this.

Comment: It seems dollar slashy strings were introduced to address this issue. I have updated the answer.

Comment: So, to summarize, in `/\\/`, the last backslash would basically escape the delimiting forward slash `/`, and therefore it all breaks down?

Comment: @Neftas: Yes, exactly. The slashy string does not get terminated correctly.